# How can I perform *ngFor in order to get all data from server? angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular

I tried to perform simple *NgFor in order to get my data organized in table, this result an error: ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

This is my HTML code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
     <!--- <th> Title </th>-->
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>End date</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Coupon Type</th>
      <th>Message</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Company Id</th>
  </tr>

  <tr *ngFor="let coupon of allCoupons">
      <td>{{coupon.id}}</td>
     <!-- <td>{{coupon.title}}</td>  -->
      <td>{{coupon.startDate}}</td>
      <td>{{coupon.endDate}}</td>
      <td>{{coupon.amount}}</td>
      <td>{{coupon.type}}</td>
      <td>{{coupon.message}}</td>
      <td>{{coupon.price}}</td>
      <td>{{coupon.image}}</td>
      <td>{{coupon.companyId}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is my component:

```
export class SearchCouponComponent implements OnInit {
  public allCoupons:Coupon[];
  public coupon: Coupon = new Coupon();


  constructor(private myCouponService:CouponService) {
   }

   ngOnInit() {
    this.myCouponService.getAllCoupon().subscribe(data =>{
      alert("inside")
      console.log(data);
      this.allCoupons = data;
      //this.allCoupons= Array.of(this.allCoupons);
      console.log("coupons are:"+this.allCoupons);
    })
  }
}
```

This is my service:

```
public getAllCoupon ():Observable<Coupon[]> {
    return this.myHttpClient.get<Coupon[]>("http://localhost:8080/couponProject/rest/loggedin/coupons");
  }
```

The result of `console.log(data)` ==> `{coupons: Array(5)}`
The result of `console.log("coupons are:"+this.allCoupons)` ==> `[object Object]`

Comment: this.allCoupons = data.coupons;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in the output of your log, `data` is an object with one field `coupons` that contains an array.

Change `this.allCoupons = data;` to `this.allCoupons = data.coupons;` so that `allCoupons` contains an array.